# Can't see Textbox text in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox

I am trying to make a DataGrid in WPF that will display the different properties of the items in a given collection. So far, everything works perfectly, except for one. Here is an image of my DataGrid, which is fully populated just as intended:

[image: Fully Populated Data Grid]

And you may already see my problem. Each and every item has a value associated with it, which is properly binded. However, I cannot see the value for any of the items unless I specifically click on that cell. For example:

[image: Data Grid With Value Showing]

I want the values to be visible at all times, just like the `Name` and `Default Value` Columns, but it is very important that the value, and only the value, is editable from the DataGrid at runtime. Here is the XAML I have in place for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Margin="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigurationParameterCollection}" Name="MasterListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="MasterListBox_SelectionChanged" AlternationCount="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1000" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

            <!-- Begin Problem Area-->

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!-- End Problem Area-->

            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Default Value" Binding="{Binding DefaultValue}"/>


        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Don't worry about the name of the DataGrid, it used to be a ListBox and I just never bothered to change the name. Everything links up perfectly, I just can't figure out why the TextBox text is not visible.

Any help you can give is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I know that I can achieve this with using `CellTemplate` instead of `CellEditingTemplate`, but the latter has the feature of only editing on two clicks, but selecting the row otherwise. I want to have this feature, so If there is a way to do that with `CellTemplate` please let me know. With `CellTemplate`, I see the boxes at all times:

[image]

I want it to be like in the second picture, where the rest of the column appears in style with the datagrid, while the cell I am editing looks like a text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
    DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate
To
    DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

---

You can specify a display template, and an edit template ...

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I used `CellEditingTemplate` because it has the feature where you must click twice on the cell to actually edit it, otherwise it looks just like the rest of the columns. Is there any way to do that with `CellTemplate`?

Comment: I tried that, and it seems to still do the same thing. To clarify, with this method the cells in the value column have a visible text box, with all of the design that comes with it, detracting from the overall style of the datagrid. I want it to only appear that way when the focus is on the specific cell I am editing.

Comment: That looks perfect, the only problem is that TextBlock does not allow me to edit the values.

Comment: And when you double click, it should change to the TextBox!

Comment: It does not for me. Am I supposed to implement some sort of logic in the code behind for that to happen?

Comment: I accidentally changed both templates to the textblock. This works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you sincerely for all of the help!

Comment: On a very tiny semantic note.... When I go to edit the cell in this way, the cell gets slightly larger, to accommodate the text box I assume. When I use a `DataGridTextColumn`(which I just figured out you can edit) for the other properties, the cell remains the same size. Is there any way to replicate this? Not a big deal, but it would be cool

Comment: You can add a style to the TextBox to remove the border and/or Padding. Glad it worked!

Comment: Just want to say thanks! You just got me past the 2k mark :0)

Comment: No problem, you earned it. Now I just need to break 100 XD